# Process form for updating records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, forms

I have built a form that is a table of fields representing multiple records in a mysql database. The table is generated dynamically base on some relational tables:

[image]

I would like to create a single Save button that will update the table if changes have been made to any of the fields for a given record in a single click.

The question that I have is how can I do this without creating seperate form tags wrapped around each table row? What is the best approach? Is it possible to do using only html and php, or is javascript required?

I would like to avoid inserting an additional column with edit buttons.

Here is the code I to generate the table:

```
function subjectResourcesForm($connection, $subjectId) {
    echo "<h2>ONLINE RESOURCES</h2>";
    echo "<div id='subject_resources_" . $section_row[$ID] . "'>\n";
    $resource_query = selectResourcesBySubject($subjectId);
    $resource_result = mysqli_query($connection, $resource_query);
    if ( mysqli_num_rows($resource_result) != 0 ) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>Position</td>";
    echo "<td>Label</td>";
    echo "<td>Link</td>";
    echo "<td>Visibility</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
        while($resource_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resource_result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" " . 
                            "name=\"resourceItemPosition_" . $resource_row['id'] . 
                            "\" value=\"" . $resource_row['position'] . "\" />";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" " . 
                            "name=\"resourceItemTitle_" . $resource_row['id'] . 
                            "\" value=\"" . $resource_row['resourceTitle'] . "\" />";
            echo "<td><input type=\"text\" " . 
                            "name=\"resourceItemLink_" . $resource_row['id'] . 
                            "\" value=\"" . $resource_row['link'] . "\" />";

            echo "<td><select name=\"resourceItemDisplay_" . $resource_row['id'] . "\">";
            if ( $resource_row['display'] == $TRUE ) {
                echo "<option value=\"1\" selected>Visible</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"0\">Hidden</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value=\"1\">Visible</option>";
                echo "<option value=\"0\" selected>Hidden</option>";
            }
            echo "</select></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    } else {
        echo "No Resources Found!";
    }
    // Save Button
    echo "<tr>" . 
            "<td colspan=\"2\">" . 
                "<button type=\"button\">Save Changes</button>" .
            "</td>" . 
    "</tr>";
    // Insert Button
    echo "<tr>" . 
            "<td colspan=\"2\">" . 
                "<button type=\"button\">Add Item</button>" .
            "</td>" . 
    "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</div><!-- End of subject_resources_" . $section_row[$ID] . "-->\n";

    // Free Result
    mysqli_free_result($resource_result);
}
```

Here is the SQL:

```
function selectResourcesBySubject($subjectId) {
        return "SELECT
                tbl_Resources.mId               AS  id,
                tbl_Resources.mTitle            AS  resourceTitle,
                tbl_Resources.mLink             AS  link,
                tbl_SubjectResources.mSubject   AS  subject, 
                tbl_SubjectResources.mResource  AS  resource,
                tbl_SubjectResources.mDisplay   AS  display,
                tbl_SubjectResources.mPosition  AS  position
            FROM
                tbl_Resources
            INNER JOIN
                tbl_SubjectResources
            ON
                tbl_SubjectResources.mResource = tbl_Resources.mId
            WHERE
                tbl_SubjectResources.mSubject = " . $subjectId .
        "   ORDER BY
                tbl_SubjectResources.mPosition ASC";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this without using JavaScript, but here is a broad ouline of one way to do it with JavaScript.

First, to every row, add a hidden field that tracks if the row has been updated:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="resourceItemUpdated_' . $resource_row['id'] . '" value="0" />';
```

Then, using the `onchange` event, set the value of the hidden field to 1 when any of the other fields on the row is modified.

Finally, in the PHP, loop through the rows and only update the database if the value of the hidden field is 1.

This solution wastes a bit of bandwith by sending all the data to the server, but it gets the job done.